Inserting range of IP's into a sql table
I have a sql table with two fields TermID and IP address. I want to insert(10.100.08.01-10.100.08.254) and each IP will have an assigned TermID for example (TERM1 -  TERM254).
I will greatly appreciate any guidance as this is not my expertise.

What is your intended result? What did you try so far, what did your insert look like?

I want to avoid creating insert statement for all the term ID's  but rather would like to have something that will start from a TERM1 and will end at TERM2 and IP that starts at 10.100.08.01 and ends at 10.100.08.254. I guess its a dynamic query which I am not versed at.

You'll find food for thought here: How to generate a 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, ... series in standard SQL or T-SQL?.

@SQL_NoExpert have a look on this example, I am not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve.

This question is similar to: Storing IP addresses - varchar(45) vs varbinary(16). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
